# I have a problem with positioning in react-native-reanimated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I want to animate the list using Animated.View, but as soon as I add it, everything that was above my list shifts up under my header if you remove Animated.View and leave just a View, then everything works as it should.
On my phone and emulator, the same problem.
I'm new to all this, maybe I misunderstood something, I would be grateful if you help

Edit: I noticed that this happens after clicking on TextInput, after that everything shifts up, I tried using KeyboardAvoidingView, but it didn't help, what am I doing wrong??

[use View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r1Vd.png)

[after use Animated.View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbhTg.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMG2D.png)